# Custom Image under AzureBatch ImageReference class not working

Tags: azure-batch

I have a custom VHD file with me. I am able to create Pool with my custom image through portal. But i want to try the same with .Net SDK. But it is throwing error "Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden".

I am referring this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.batch.imagereference.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Batch_ImageReference__ctor_System_String_)  Azure Batch

I am able to create Pool from MarketPlace images from same code
Below is my code

```
ImageReference imageReference = new ImageReference("/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/RG-OneGolden/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/OMGoldenImage");


                VirtualMachineConfiguration virtualMachineConfiguration =
                new VirtualMachineConfiguration(
                    imageReference: imageReference,
                    nodeAgentSkuId: "batch.node.windows amd64");

                try
                {
                    CloudPool pool = batchClient.PoolOperations.CreatePool(
                        poolId: PoolId,
                        targetDedicatedComputeNodes: PoolNodeCount,
                        virtualMachineSize: PoolVMSize,
                        virtualMachineConfiguration: virtualMachineConfiguration);

                    pool.Commit();
                }
                catch (BatchException be)
                {
                    // Accept the specific error code PoolExists as that is expected if the pool already exists
                    if (be.RequestInformation?.BatchError?.Code == BatchErrorCodeStrings.PoolExists)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The pool {0} already existed when we tried to create it", PoolId);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw; // Any other exception is unexpected
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure you have met the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/batch/batch-custom-images#prerequisites) for custom images in Azure Batch:

1. The ARM Image is in the same subscription and region as the Batch account.
2. You are using Azure Active Directory to authenticate with the Batch service.